# Send emoji via telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am trying to send emojis via my telegram bot but I can not send it when I take it from an array or a variable.

If I a do this in PHP, it works:

```
$emoji = "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81";
echo $emoji;
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
$emoji = "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81";
$content = array('chat_id' => $id, 'text' => $emoji);
$telegram->sendMessage($content);
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**:
It doesn't show anything.
I've tried with `define` and it works, but I need array or variables to do it conditionally.

```
define(emoji, "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81");
$content = array('chat_id' => $id, 'text' => emoji);
$telegram->sendMessage($content);
```

I think there is a problem with quotes.

**UPDATE2**: Problem solved, thanks to [these link](https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot/issues/48) provided by @CaldwellYSR.

You have to send it this way:

```
$emoji = "\xE2\x98\x94";
$content = array('chat_id' => $id, 'text' => json_decode('"'.$emoji.'"');
$telegram->sendMessage($content);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you `var_dump($telegram->sendMessage($content))` as far as I know using a constant vs a string shouldn't make a difference. I'm trying to get at the expected output vs the actual output. I don't know anything about telegram-bot but the PHP is valid.

Comment: https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot/issues/48

Does this link help?

Comment: Yes @CaldwellYSR, this helps me a lote. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to sendMessage on the array. You need to access the 'text' key in the array like so:

```
$telegram->sendMessage($content["text"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not the problem. You have to pass an array to this function. It is working with some other text.

Comment: You should probably edit your question with more information then. Based on the code you've showed, the string should show. Maybe show us what your results are?